# Is it possible to use my custom schedule.js for rendering the schedule component in primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I am using schedule component of primefaces. I had to change the schedule.js in primefaces jar file to implement tooltip for the schedule event. Is there a way that schedule component takes a custom local javascript file other than read from primefaces jar.

**Edit:**

```
<h:head>
    <title>#{serviceCalendarViewBean.currentInstance} - Schedule</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="#{request.contextPath}/css/common.css" />
    <h:outputText value="#{serviceCalendarViewBean.employeeStyleClass}"
        escape="false" />
</h:head>
<h:body onload="checkURL()">
    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/views/Header.xhtml" />
    <div class="belly">
        <ui:include src="servicemenu.xhtml" />
        <f:view contentType="text/html">
            <h:form prependId="false" id="mainForm">
                <p:hotkey bind="esc" handler="noteWidget.hide();eventDialog.hide();" />
                <!-- For Ajax Pop-up Box -->
                <p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();"
                    onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();" />
                <div class="mainColWrapper">
                    <p:panel>
                        <p:schedule id="schedule"
                            value="#{serviceCalendarViewBean.eventModel}"
                            widgetVar="scheduleWidget" draggable="true" resizable="false"
                            allDaySlot="true" slotMinutes="15"
                            initialDate="#{serviceCalendarViewBean.miniCalDate}"
                            view="agendaWeek" leftHeaderTemplate="today, ,prev,next"
                            rightHeaderTemplate="agendaDay,agendaWeek,month">

                        </p:schedule>
                    </p:panel>
                </div>
            </h:form>
        </f:view>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function removeImageOrNotesIcon() {
            var ss = document.getElementById('idReccurFreq').value;
            jQuery('span').remove('.ico-dialogBox');
        }
    </script>
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="js/schedule.js" />
</h:body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="schedule.js"/>
```

The h:outputscript checks for files in webcontent/resources folder. If we are specifying library like 'primefaces' or 'js' there should be a folder inside the 'resources' folder in the corresponding name. So in the above code as we specified primefaces, the file should be in 'webcontent/resources/primefaces/schedule.js'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just include it inside your `<h:head>` tag.
For example:

`<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="resources/js/schedule.js"/>`

Comment: i tried it but no effect, should i add the version of primeface jar along with the primefaces in library attribute? Like __library="primefaces"__ __library="primefaces-4.0"__

Comment: No. Version doesn't matter. It will fetch whatever current version you're using.

Comment: Also check that `schedule.js` path is correct or not.

Comment: `  <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="../../../js/schedule.js"/>
</h:body>` should i change the location of the js file to resources/js?

Comment: Yes. The path you've given might be incorrect. Please change it to resources/js

Comment: i don't have a resources folder in my project structure, i have a js folder in WebContent, so i placed the schedule.js in WebContent/js and my .xhtml file is in Webcontent/WEB-INF/views/service. So i referred the schedule.js as name="../../../js/schedule.js". So i think the path specified in the _outputscript_ is correct.

Comment: No. This path is not relative to your .xhtml file. Try this.
`<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="js/schedule.js"/>`

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the portion where you are including this output script?

Comment: Put `<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="js/schedule.js" />` inside your `<h:head>` tag

Comment: i have tried the following.  `<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="js/schedule.js" />`  
`<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="../../../js/schedule.js" />`  
`<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="../../../resources/js/schedule.js" />`  
When i check the page source i get the following.  
`<script type="text/javascript" src="RES_NOT_FOUND"></script>`

Comment: My only question is whether this is inside `<h:head>` tag or not.

Comment: yes it is inside `h:head`. I got it worked. I created a folder 'resources' inside that a folder 'primefaces' and when I placed schedule.js in the primefaces folder it worked. So i guess if we specify the library as primefaces we have to create a folder primefaces. The primefaces/jsf looks in resources folder if using outputscript. Thanks for your time and help.